# tsql: if exist and cross join issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm having a bit of an issue:

```
Table   
Name: Table_test
       -------
Column: test
       -------
        test1
        test2 
        test3

Required Results
  test  |  test
 --------------
  test1 | test2
```

Along with the expected results above, I need to see if the value 'test1' exists, if not then output the value 'NONE' in its place. I'm connecting to a Microsoft SQL 2012 server. Here is my code so far:

```
SELECT a.test, b.test FROM (
IF EXISTS
(SELECT test FROM Table_test WHERE test='test1')
SELECT test FROM Table_test WHERE test='test1' 
ELSE 
SELECT test='NONE') a
CROSS JOIN
(SELECT test FROM Table_test WHERE test='test2') b;
```

The IF EXIST...ELSE part is not working.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: And just what, pray tell, does "having a bit of an issue" mean?

Comment: And what aspects of that horrible query are there because they are somehow required?  I mean, do you really have to use an `IF` expression?  Do you really need to use `EXISTS`?

Comment: No, I'm ok  with other methods of achieving the same. Thanks.

Comment: what is your issue? what is your output and what is your expected output?

Comment: I have the expected output in the question.  The problem that I have is with the IF EXIST...ELSE statement.  I need to see if the value 'test1' exists, if it doesn't then output the value 'NONE' in its place.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't care how you get the desired result from the given table, one of the simpler non-trivial queries that would achieve your objective is

```
SELECT *
FROM
  Table_test a
  CROSS JOIN Table_test b
WHERE a.test = 'test1' AND b.test = 'test2'
```

It's hard to see how that is generalizable to a real problem, of course, but that's more a characteristic of the question than of the answer.

**Edited to add:**

To address your additional requirement, you could do this:

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 from Table_test WHERE test = 'test1') THEN 'test1'
    ELSE 'NONE'
  END test,
  *
FROM
  Table_test
WHERE test = 'test2'
```

There's no join in it, but you don't need one to achieve the desired result.  Note in particular the `CASE` *expression* -- this produces a value, in this case either 'test1' or 'NONE'.  In contrast, `IF` introduces a tsql control *statement*, which does not produce a value.  You might use an `IF` statement in the implementation of a stored procedure, but not ordinarily in a query.

Comment: If the value 'test1' doesn't exist, I would like it to return value 'NONE'

Comment: @Corey, That would have been appropriate to express in your question in the first place.  Anyway, I have updated my answer.